# Truck routing with road restrictions here maps

Tags: android, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I want to render truck restrictions like weight and height on the map like in this link map:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/truck-routing-road-restrictions

My question is how can I render these restriction in my android project app and I want to if possible make the restrictions available offline as well. I have made offline map downloadable as well in my project but how can I show restrictions. My map is just plain map without those restrictions.

Is it possible with Here sdk for android (Premium edition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to render truck restrictions on the map using [setFleetFeaturesVisible](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.19/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#setFleetFeaturesVisible-java.util.EnumSet-) method with TRUCK_RESTRICTIONS value.

```
map.fleetFeaturesVisible = EnumSet.of(Map.FleetFeature.TRUCK_RESTRICTIONS)
```

[image]